# Regarding the submit button in adaptive cards

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

My question is regarding the submit button in adaptive cards. I'm implementing an adaptive card for the date of birth in of the records. Till now, I have implemented a date picker where the default value of the date picker will be the user's DOB present in the records. I need to disable to the "Update" button until/unless the user changes the default value. Is it possible to implement the date picker in this manner? I'm attaching the screen shot of the date picker that I've implemented till now. Thanks in advance.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDGbQ.png%60)

```
public static Attachment DatePickerAttachment(string givenDob, string maxDate, string minDate)
            {
                var card = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 2));

                card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                {
                    Text = $"Please enter the date",
                    Wrap = true,
                    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default,
                    Spacing = AdaptiveSpacing.Medium
                });

                var inputDate = new AdaptiveDateInput()
                {
                    Id = "date",
                    Placeholder = "Please enter the date",
                    Value = $"{givenDob}",
                    Max = $"{maxDate}",
                    Min = $"{minDate}"
                };

                card.Body.Add(inputDate);

                var dataObj = new SimpleObjClass()
                {
                    value = "go on with the process"
                };

                var action = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
                {
                    Title = "Update",
                    Data = dataObj,
                };
                card.Actions.Add(action);



                var dataObj2 = new SimpleObjClass() { value = "kill the process" };
                var action1 = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
                {
                    Title = "Cancel",
                    Data = dataObj2,
                };
                card.Actions.Add(action1);

                var attachment = new Attachment
                {
                    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                    Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card)),
                };
                return attachment;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image, it looks like you are using the Web Chat channel. I believe the 1.3 schema is supported, which means you could look to use the native validation in the Adaptive Card, specifically the "isRequired" and "errorMessage" properties.

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Input.Date",
            "isRequired": true,
            "errorMessage": "Please select a date",
            "id": "Date",
            "label": "Date",
            "value": "10/10/2020"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Update"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Adaptive card demo]

Comment: Hi @Steve Johnson, thank you for the reply, I think you did not understand my question, my question was the update must be disabled or throws an errorMessage, until the user selects a data rather than the default date on the data picker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a recorded process of how I understood it - was this not correct? My understanding was that the Update button to throw an error if a date has not been selected.

Comment: Hi @Steve, yeah this is not what I was expecting, instead of dd/mm/yyyy, you have a default value say 21/10/2002, the Update button must throw an error if the default date is not changed on the selection of Update

Comment: Hi @Steve, I guess you understand my intention, sorry I don't have nothing to show you visually.

Comment: No problem, is the DOB value being populated in your Adaptive Card already? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, my intention is change a user's DOB in one of my data bases, when he asks the bot to change the DOB, the bot shows an adaptive card with a prepopulated value, which is nothing but the user's DOB in the DB, the user must not be able to click the update button, until he changes the prepopulated value, about your question, till now, I have just created a date picker using json and C# sdk. I'm not understanding on how to implement an adaptive card, with the above intention.

Comment: Okay, so you have the database API set up in your bot and it's pulling the value through or is that what you are intending to achieve? It might be easier to identify what you are missing if you are able to post the code you have so far.

Comment: Yes, I have the data base API through which I get the DOB of the user. I'm attaching the adaptive cards code that I've written.

Comment: Have you tried using the updated schema since I can see you are using 1.2 I think?

Comment: Yeah for C# SDK, I'm changed all the versions and tried, but I did not get what I wanted, I hope you understood my intention.

Comment: If the “isRequired” and “errorMessage” properties of the 1.3 schema doesn’t fulfil your requirement, you may need to look to handle it another way. Another way you might want to look at is using dialogs.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/43.complex-dialog

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the recommendation, I'm actually using waterfall dialogs to implement them. Is there any way to modify the errorMessage and isRequired methods, so that if the default value is not changed, the date picker can throw an error.

Comment: Not that I’m aware of sadly. I’ve tended to handle validation on Adaptive Cards using dialogs, specifically the replaceDialog function.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you Steve for your suggestions.